# ¿Cómo se traduce "El Dibu" al inglés?

Tags: traducción, inglés, argentina

https://www.clarin.com/deportes/mensaje-dibu-martinez-dt-aston-villa-hablaremos-celebraciones-_0_a3lyflXPd4.html

Soy seguidor del Aston Villa

¿Cómo se traduce "El Dibu" al inglés?

Por favor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

***El Dibu**, protagonista de la serie argentina "**Mi Familia es un Dibujo**"*

El apodo del "**Dibu**" (*Damián Emiliano Martínez*), le viene porque de niño se parecía al personaje de aquella serie, tenía pecas y su pelo tiraba a pelirrojo.

Una posible traducción al inglés, aunque los apodos y los nombres no deberían ser traducidos, podría ser *"The drw / drwe"* o "*toon*" de cartoon.

Comment: la traducción de Google es "the drawing" en inglés. Gracias y feliz navidad Diego

Comment: ¡Gracias a ti! Feliz Navidad.

Comment: Although toon has the advantage of being more easily pronounceable not the in a football context Toon Army refers to supporters of Newcastle United.

Answer (score 2):

*El Dibu* es un apodo del portero de Argentina, Emiliano Martínez (también el actual portero del Antón Villa como bien dices), por lo que en inglés también se conoce como *Dibu*.

Answer (score 0):

Los nombres propios casi nunca deben traducirse. Salvo algunas excepciones (que en general son históricas, por ejemplo: Thomas More se tradució al castellano como Tomás Moro) si alguien se llama Peter, le tenés que decir Peter, no Pedro. Las personas de habla inglesa (supongo que lo sos por cómo hiciste tu pregunta) suelen usar la misma regla, por lo que tu pregunta no tiene sentido.

Comment: Jeje, mira, yo creo que como la mitad de las preguntas que se hacen en este sitio no son para "usar" las respuestas, sino sólo con el ánimo de saber. Es obvio que el usuario que hace la pregunta no va a traducir después el apodo, nadie lo haría. Sólo quería saber por qué le dicen Dibu, esa es una inquietud válida y requiere que alguien le ayude con la traducción.